# Get property name from it's value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, delegates, lambda

How does Microsoft MVC know that the name of the property is "Phone" since we have only the object instance and one of it's properties' value?

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't got the property's *value* - you've got an [*expression tree*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) which tells you how to obtain the value from an item. That expression tree can be analyzed by the framework to find the property name.

Now if it were

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x.Phone) %>
```

then *that* would genuinely be just getting the value... but the lambda expression is being converted into an expression tree by the C# compiler.

Comment: Nice! Does all lambda expressions work this way or this is a special case?

Answer (score 3):

[They are using this 'trick'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)